# Are there any errors in this schematic?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am trying to make my own board based on the Wemos d1 mini v1. This is the original schematic - [image]
And this is what I have so far for my custom one - [image]
If you see any errors, I would much appreciate them being pointed out! I switched from the CH340G to the CH340C to get rid of the oscillating crystal. (I am making a lot of these, so the less parts the better)
Edit - I switched back. the CH340C was out of stock. I think that crystal would work.

Comment: JP1 and JP2 are missing in the new schematic.

Comment: It's a circuit and all circuits are valid until it is stated what is expected from them. So, to judge whether your circuit is valid requires a statement from you on precisely what the functionality is meant to be.

Comment: @Aaron Oh i'm sorry! I excluded them on purpose. There not needed for my use! Sorry for not clarifying!

Comment: @Andyaka I need it to work the same as a Wemos d1 mini, except with built in Led's. (I dont really know of a better way to explain it. this is the first time ive done anything like this really)

Comment: Well, on this site, any question that require the tear-down of a commercial product are closed unless full schematics of those commercial products are available. Are you saying that the top schematic is from the commercial product you mentioned? If you are then it's probably OK but, you ought to provide hyperlinks to the original diagrams (if for nothing else as a citation).

Comment: Yes, the top schematic is the official schematic for the board I mentioned.

Comment: Then add a hyperlink - diagrams stolen from other places need citations.

Comment: Ok I will try and find the link I used.

Comment: It depends what counts as an error. There seems to be a few differences, but are they errors or on purpose? Maybe if you explained what you modified and why? And tell us how you expect the device to work. For example even if there is no errors, some things may be just designed poorly. For example there is a good chance the RGB LEDs may not work, is that an error?

Comment: @Justme Ok. So I Modified it in these ways - 
1) I changed from CH340G to CH340C and got rid of the oscillating crystal
2) I added all the leds, which are WS2812 addressable leds. 
3) I removed the bars of pins since I dont need them (JP1 and JP2) 
5) I removed the reset button. (Key 1) 

I think thats it. I just need the Led's to function as Neo pixels. ( I was using external ones soldered on, but I want them built in) 

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to reviewing the schematic diagram, I recommend producing a netlist file (text file) and reviewing that. Pay attention to power and ground routes. A clean looking schematic can actually contain net errors that won't show up in the diagram.

Comment: @icodeplenty Ok will do! Do the Led's look ok? I couldnt find solid information about how to correctly wire them.

Comment: @icodeplenty Thanks! That advice really helped!

Comment: The LEDs appear to be wired correctly to me in the diagram. When placing the parts on the PCB, be sure to place all bypass caps closest to the IC power pins.

Comment: @icodeplenty Ok good. Yep! thats what I did. I made sure to place all the caps closest to were they are meant to be. Thanks!

Comment: Spend a little time to make the schematic more readable. You have many doglegs for no reason and ensure you only have the red dots where there is a junction. You have net labels for, say GPIO4, but no corresponding label on the esp12 module.

Comment: For sure! Im going to update the question, since I have worked on it today a bunch.

Comment: I'm assuming that you need to duplicate the schematic in order to use a PCB layout tool. In that case, why not layout the schematic exactly as the original? Put JP1 and JP2 in the upper left corner with the 5V to 3V3 regulator to the right. Use the same component annotation and the same net names. Make the two drawings look as identical as possible. After you've done that I'll invest the 60 seconds it will take to verify that they're the same.

Comment: @Andyaka, Wemos D1 mini is a well known open hardware development board. there is a suspicion it is the most popular Arduino board

Comment: @SupaNova  Thanks for the advice, i'll organize the diagram.